# Send attachment to MYSQL from Lotus Notes

Tags: mysql, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to fetch the attachments present in the documents of a view in Lotus Notes Application and send them to sql table, can we do that?

Is there any limitations on connecting Domino server and SQL server (eg. they should be present in same lan etc.?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can for instance create a Java agent that uses the [MySQL JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/) to connect to MySQL. You can then process the required documents and attachments.

Keith Strickland has blogged about [using XPages and Java to connect to MySQL](http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=7FF651F56323CD2C85257920000494C6). Perhaps this an be useful for you.

The Domino server obviously needs to be able to connect to the MySQL server in terms of network access and authorization to use the MySQL server.